# How to convert passive voice to active voice?

Tags: passive-voice, active-voice, software-bugs

I am using a proofreading plugin for Wordpress and it says that I should not use passive voice (the selected parts) in the following phrase. How can I rephrase this to use active voice?

> The invalid profile **is discarded** and a new fresh profile **is created**.

Comment: This is the kind of sentence passive voice was made for. Ignore Wordpress.

Comment: Hello Alex V, and Welcome to EL&U.

Comment: Susan should get the 'Welcoming Smile' hat.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that unless you can add a subject

> The system discards the invalid profile and creates a new fresh profile.
>
> The moderator discards the invalid profile and creates a new fresh profile.

then **the passive here works fine**, because the only construction(s) I could formulate would be clunkier:

> The invalid profiles undergoes deletion and the creation of a new fresh profile takes place.

Comment: And even if you ***can*** add a subject, you should only do it if it improves the writing, which in this case I think is very unlikely.

Comment: Passive smoking is the one to avoid.

Comment: Apparently, 'works finely' _is_ an allowable form of the far more common 'works fine' (my edit here), but I'd say it's hardly idiomatic English.